# How to call constructor and ngOnInit after login

Tags: angular5, jhipster

I define a route '' for HomeComponent, there is a login link in the component's html page, after login(), the url is not changed, and the constructor and ngOnInit are not called, so the {{currentSubject?.name}} is blank, then if I press F5 to refresh the page, ngOnInit will be called, and {{currentSubject?.name}} will be shown in the page.

My question is: How can I do to call ngOnInit to make currentSubject.name shown in the page after login?:

The html page is as below:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="isAuthenticated()">
 <div *ngSwitchCase="false" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <span class="hipster img-fluid rounded"></span>
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-9">
   <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <span>existing account, please </span>
    <Button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="login()" jhiTranslate="global.messages.info.authenticated.link">login</Button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div *ngSwitchCase="true">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ngbDropdownToggle href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       {{currentSubject?.name}}
      </a>
      <div *ngIf="currentSubject" ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let subject of subjects" href="#">{{subject.name}}</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1#</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2#</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

The ngOnInit() is as below:

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
            this.account = account;
        });
        this.registerAuthenticationSuccess();

        this.profileService.getProfileInfo().then((profileInfo) => {
            this.swaggerEnabled = profileInfo.swaggerEnabled;
        });

        this.subjectService.query({
            page: 0,
            size: this.itemsPerPage,
            sort: ['id', 'asc']
        }).subscribe(
            (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onSuccess(res.json, res.headers),
            (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json)
        );
    }
```

The subects and currentSubject will be populated in the onSuccess function which I skip here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining currentSubject.name in ngOnInit, do it by subscribing to a successful authentication event which can be done with eventManager

```
this.eventManager.subscribe('authenticationSuccess', (data) => {*code here*});
```